# Unit test for spring ws-client - check if marshalSendAndReceive is being invoked

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-security, spring-ws

my goal is writing a unit test for my `WebServiceClientImpl` class and I want to add a test that checks if `marshalSendAndReceive` is being invoked. I use `Mockito` and `powermockito` framework. I need to use `powermockito` because `WebServiceGatewaySupport.getWebServiceTemplate` is a final method, which `mockito` cant do.

This is the class that I want to test.

```
public class WebServiceClientImpl extends WebServiceGatewaySupport implements
WebServiceClient {

@Override
public <T> T execute(final Object requestPayload,
                   final Class<T> responseType,
                   final String soapActionCallBack) {
return (T) getWebServiceTemplate()
             .marshalSendAndReceive(requestPayload, new 
                                    SoapActionCallback(soapActionCallBack));
}
```

This is my unit test so far.

```
RunWith( PowerMockRunner.class )
@PowerMockRunnerDelegate( HierarchicalContextRunner.class )
@PrepareForTest( WebServiceClientImpl.class )
public class WebServiceClientImplTest {

private WebServiceClientImpl webServiceClientImpl = PowerMockito.mock(WebServiceClientImpl.class);

@Mock
private WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate;

@Before
public void before() {
  MockitoAnnotations.initMocks( this );
}

public class Execute {
  Object response = "response";
  Object request = "request";
  SoapActionCallback soapActionCallBack = new SoapActionCallback("soap");

  @Before
  public void before() {

  when( webServiceClientImpl.getWebServiceTemplate() ).thenReturn( webServiceTemplate );
  when( webServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive ( request, soapActionCallBack) ).thenReturn(response);
  response = webServiceClientImpl.execute( request, Object.class, "soapActionCallBack" );
  System.out.println ("RESPONSE " + response );
}


@Test
public void marshalSendAndReceiveInvoked() {
  verify( webServiceTemplate ).marshalSendAndReceive( request, soapActionCallBack );
}

@Test
public void webServiceClientReturnValue() {
  assertEquals( "response", response );
}}}
```

However the response is still null, even though I have put this in the unit test.

`when( webServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive ( request, soapActionCallBack) ).thenReturn(response)`

Can anyone helps with the unit test? Any help will be appreciated - Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java Reflection API and change reference of WebServiceTemplate in WebServiceGatewaySupport manually (and mock it using Mockito):

```
WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplateMock = mock(WebServiceTemplate.class);

Field webServiceTemplateRef = client.getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredField("webServiceTemplate");
webServiceTemplateRef.setAccessible(true);
webServiceTemplateRef.set(client, webServiceTemplate);
```

Now you are able to mock behavior of the template:

```
Mockito.when(webServiceTemplateMock.marshalSendAndReceive(request, soapActionCallBack)).thenReturn(response);
```